# Vim key binding to call function: control+c then 1

Tags: vim, key-bindings, vim-plugin

I am looking for a way to make a vim binding where I can enter control C (both the control and c keys at the same time), then another option (similar to `yy` or `dd`. For example, ctrl+c then 1 would be set so that a function I define, called my func, would be called  like so: `myfunc(1)`

Here is my attempt so far: `map <C-A> <F1>:call myfunc(1)<CR>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it, with a few amendments:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> is used for interrupt signals; choose some other key combination, such as `<Leader>c`
- It's a lot easier to do it with counts than arguments; that is, trigger the key combination with <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, rather than with <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>
- User functions must have names beginning with upper case letters.

With these notes, you might do it like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>c :<C-u>call MyFunc(v:count)<CR>
```

`v:count` is a predefined variable that takes the value of the counter you passed to the last normal mode command, or 0 if there was no counter.  There's also `v:count1` that does the same thing, except it defaults to 1 if there was no counter.

Comment: What is the signifigance of `<C-u>`? I'm having trouble making this work. Do you see anything wrong with `noremap <silent> <C-S> :call Myfunc(v:count)<CR>`? I have it set this way, but cannot access the function with ctrl+a....

Comment: Yes, your map is wrong.  `<C-u>` is needed, it removes the count after `:`.  `<C-s>` is the key for stop signal, you won't be able to map it.  `<C-a>` adds the count to the character under the cursor.  You probably could map it if you're really determined, but you shouldn't.  There are preciously few `Ctrl` keys that don't already do something important. _shrug_